# FFMPEG convert RTSP to HTTP streaming video

Tags: http, video, ffmpeg, ip-camera

I have a IpCam that send streaming video only on rtsp://ipaddress/live.
My software accept only streaming video over HTTP.

So I thing that could use FFMPEG to convert streaming from RTSP to HTTP.

I have installed FFMPEG on Windows 7 and I have try an example to convert RTSP to video file: `ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.43:1256 -r 15 C:/output/video.mp4` and it works.

Can any help me to convert RTSP to HTTP streaming (i use Windows 7 S.O.).

Thank you.

Comment: Any impovements? Faced same issue with Jovision IP-cams.